# ASP.NET Core MVC Bind Viewmodel that contains 2 Domain Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a simple Web Application with ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC Framework and Entity Framework Core.

I have 2 domain models: `Renter` and `Address`, and a view model `RenterViewModel`:

```
public class Renter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public Type RenterType { get; set;}

    public string CompanyName { get; set;}

    [Required]       
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public string LastName { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public Address Address {get; set;}
    
    public int AddressId {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public Address()
    { }
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    
    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
   
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class RenterViewModel
{
    public RenterViewModel(Renter renter, Address address)
    {
        this.Renter = renter;
        this.Address = address;
    }

    public Renter Renter {get; set;}
    public Address Address {get; set;}       
}
```

For my index view and details view this works fine.

How can I bind this view model in the controller and validate it, in order to store the `Address` to the database first and then after it the `Renter` to the database?

`Renter` needs the `Id` of `Address` because of a foreign key constraint.

My `RenterController` `Create` method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,RenterType,CompanyName,FirstName,LastName"), prefix="Renter"] Renter renter,
    [Bind("Street, StreetNumber, City, Postalcode"), prefix="Address"] Address address)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(address);
            renter.Address_Id = address.id;
            _context.Add(renter);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(new RenterViewModel(renter, address));
}
```

The problem is that `ModelState.IsValid` is always false.

Comment: I think ModelState is not working with nested models, but only on first level. You need create custom validation.

Comment: Entity Framework will take care of the foreign keys when inserted, so you don't need to worry about the Address being saved first. The validation you can do on your own. You might want to look into [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/).

Comment: you really don't need viewmodel. just standard entity framework model will be fine. entity framework core can take care of everything. it will insert foreign id for you if you have their relationship in database. you just need 2 lines for saving both renter and address is _context.Add(address); await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created sample and table script for you. Please check this url https://gofile.io/d/yorkiv

I use scaffold-dbcontext to generate dbcontext and models.

### HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(Address address, Renter renter)
    {
        using (var context = new TestDBContext())
        {
            address.Renter.Add(renter);
            context.Add(address);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```